Find a function whose graph is the bottom half of this parabola: $x+(y-1)^2=0$

Find a function whose graph is the bottom half of this parabola: $x+(y-1)^2=0$

$(y-1)^2=-x$
$y-1=\pm\sqrt{-x}$
$y=1\pm\sqrt{-x}$
Bottom half $= 1-\sqrt{-x}$
My question is if I approached the problem this way: $x+y^2-2y+1=0$, I basically cannot solve for $y$ because there are two terms with different powers. So fundamentally, I don't really understand the gist of this problem because it seems to me a gimmick having to know that you don't open up the paranthesis encapsulating $y$ in the beginning. Or in other words, mathematically it seems I'm doing two different things depending on whether I open up the paranthesis or not. But I'm solving this equation for $y$ all the same. Can someone explain to me why?

You can apply the quadratic formula for your new expression and you would get the same solutions for $y$.

$y^2-2y=-x-1$. How do I apply the quadratic equation to this with two variables?

If you are solving for $y$, that is the only variable that matters to you.
$$y^2 - 2y + x+1 = 0 \implies y = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(x+1)}}{2} = 1\pm\sqrt{-x}$$

So $(x+1)$ is considered a constant here?

It is not a constant since that is the independent variable of your function that varies to build the graph, but the quadratic formula works anyway to solve for $y$. It is a slower method than the one you propose at the beginning though.
